# How to listening new XLM transaction for multiple accounts

Tags: transactions, accounts, javascript-sdk, xlm

I'm totally new in stellar network. I have experienced create transaction listener for bitcoin and ethereum by listen to every new transaction, if that transaction contain my address it send callback to the system.
I have check stellar bridge, but from what I read it's only listen for one account.
So what is the best way to listening new XLM transaction for multiple accounts ? I'm using nodejs SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The account is optional, if you don't specify it you'll get all. Note that a stellar transaction contains one or more operations, so you probably rather want to have a stream for any operation no matter what the transaction or there is even an endpoint for only payment operations. Example:

```
 horizon.payments()
            .cursor('now')
            // .forAccount( ... ) <= this is optional
            .stream( ... );
```

Comment: can you add multiple accounts to specifically listen to those multiple accounts or does it only allow 1 account in the field?